# Wifi disconnects every so often with Broadcom BCM4331, even with 13.04.

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

My wifi connection drops about every few minutes or so, and the only way to reconnect is to disable wireless, reenable it, and reconnect. As you can imagine, this is really annoying.

There are similar questions to this one, but the solutions they offer are to install Ubuntu 13.04, which I'm already running.

```
└─>lspci | grep 802
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 02)

└─>lsmod | grep b43
b43                   378642  0 
mac80211              606457  2 b43,zd1211rw
cfg80211              510937  3 b43,mac80211,zd1211rw
ssb                    56986  1 b43
bcma                   41051  1 b43
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the correct proprietary driver from http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-13.10/ubuntu-restricted-amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb/download/ by clicking the "Binary Package" link near bottom of page. Ensure the version that you are installing is 6.20.115.1 or 6.30.223.30 (both have worked for me). Version 5.100 will not work. This is a proprietary driver and should improve the network speed and stability compared to using the b43 package which is the best alternative. Even though it does not list bcm4331 as a supported card, the driver works no problem. To install the driver, simply double click the downloaded package and follow normal installation in Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: How do I install this source? I installed the package and rebooted but there doesn't seem to be any change.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this when I was still relatively new to Ubuntu, I also had the same probalem and found a guide somewhere on the internet that told me to download this package from somewhere (I can't remeber where it was now) but if you click the "Binary Package" button on this page: 
http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-13.10/ubuntu-restricted-amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.30+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb/download/ 
you can get the package, then just double click once it's downloaded and it'll be opened with the Ubuntu Software Centre. Then just click install and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can run

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

worked for me on Ubuntu 13.10 32bit